# c# coded UI project. Coded UI Test Builder doesn't record WinForm start

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I have a Solution with a WinForm and a coded UI Test Project.
I would like to test my WinForm application with a coded UI Test.

When I record my actions with the UI Test builder it doesn't record the start of my WinForm application! Everything else like clicking buttons gets recorded.

So when I then run my test it fails cause the test can't find the WinForm (obviously)...

But why is that? 
Can I add some code in the test method to start the Winform application?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Coded UI to launch your forms application on start of a test, use the method

```
ApplicationUnderTest.Launch("FORMS_APP_PATH");
```

You can check the precise method details on MSDN.

Update:

To handle changing paths I created a new Forms solution and called it LabPlus.
I then added a CodedUI test project to it.
Inside the test project I added the reference of the LabPlus assembly.
After that, I wrote following line in my CUI test method:

```
ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(LabPlus.Form1)).Location);
```

I hope this answers your question :)

Comment: So you have to build your solution first and then link the .exe file of the application right?

I did that now... it works!

What if that directory always changes? Because a lot of people get that solution from a TFS and save it on their computers somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you're right.
For changing directories, try to make it a relative path using dots and backslashes. Another option might using any of the following properties:
TestContext.DeploymentDirectory
TestContext.TestRunDirectory

Comment: It is also possible to add a full path to your Coded UI test app.config file.

Comment: I was able to launch the application under test even if its path keeps changing. I've added the solution to the main answer so that it remains more prominently visible to general public.

Comment: Why not include it as a deployment item? It then gets copies to the OUT directory which also is the tests current directory.

Comment: Yes, you can add it as a deployment item too. But, that would create too many copies of the .exe file and I think that would be pointless.

Answer (score 0):

My fix:

1. add reference from test project to WinForm project
2. decorate test class with `[DeploymentItem('your-app.exe')]` attribute
3. add `ApplicationUnderTest.Launch("your-app.exe");` to the test method